# ES / TS decoractors for instance validation

Tags: javascript, validation, typescript, decorator

I would like to use decorators to validate my instances:

```
 function min(minVal) {
    return (target, key) => {
        let value = target[key];

        const getter = () =>  value;
        const setter = (val) => {
            if (val < minVal) {
                throw new Error(`Value smaller than ${minVal}`);
            }
            value = val;
        }
        Reflect.deleteProperty[key];
        Reflect.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter
        });
    }
}

function max, String, Number ...

class User {

   @String
   name: String

   @Number
   @max(100)
   @min(0)
   age: Number

   static validate(obj) {
      ???
   }
}
```

This works when I use the instance directly, but I would like to be able to call the validate method and pass in a plain object:

```
User.validate({ name: 'Jon', age: 23}) // ok
User.validate({ name: 'Jon', age: -5}) // error
```

Is there some way to apply the decorators to the passed object without creating a User instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is a problem with your implementation of the backing field. Because you use the local variable `value` which lives in a function that is invoked once for the class+property on which the decorator is used, all instances will share the same backing field for a property, for example the following code will not work as expected:

```
class User {
   @min(0)
   age: Number
}

var u = new User();
u.age =  1;
var u2 = new User();
u2.age =  2;

console.log(u.age); // outputs 2 instead of 1
console.log(u2.age); // outputs 2
```

To run the validations on an object literal you could keep a static list of all validators, and have the decorator add to this static list when invoked. An implementation for this could look like this (the code also fixes the problem I mentioned above):

```
function validation(validator) : PropertyDecorator & MethodDecorator{
    return (target, key: PropertyKey, propDesc?: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        let privateKey = "_" + key.toString();
        propDesc = propDesc || {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
        };
        propDesc.get = propDesc.get || (function () { return this[privateKey] });

        const originalSetter = propDesc.set || (function (val) { this[privateKey] = val });
        propDesc.set = function (val) {
            validator(val);
            originalSetter.call(this, val);
        }

        const validators: Array<(target: object) => void> = target.constructor['validators'] || (target.constructor['validators'] = []);
        validators.push((target) => {
            validator(target[key]);
        })

        return propDesc;
    }
}
function min(minVal) {
    return validation((val) => {
        if (val < minVal) {
            throw new Error(`Value smaller than ${minVal}`);
        }
    });
}

function max(maxValue) {
    return validation((val) => {
        if (val > maxValue) {
            throw new Error(`Value greater than ${maxValue}`);
        }
    });
}

class User {
    static validators: Array<(target: object) => void> = [];
    static validate(obj: Partial<User>) {
        User.validators.forEach(fn => fn(obj));
    }
    @min(0) @max(100)
    age: number

    private _ageField : number;
    @min(0) @max(100)
    get ageProp(): number {
        return this._ageField;
    }
    set ageProp(value: number) {
        this._ageField = value;
    }

}
User.validate({
    age: 10, 
    ageProp: 10
});

var u = new User();
u.age = 10;
u.ageProp = 10;
```

**Edit:** Updated answer to work with properties not just fields.